# C# Find list string element that suffix of them is greater than others

Tags: c#, list

I have a list string: 
["a1","b0","c0","a2","c1","d3","a3"].
I want to get a list ["a3","d3","c1","b0"] base on suffix of them.
Example: "a1","a2","a3" . Result of them is "a3".
This question may be simple but I can't solve.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Because of I don't have right way to solve this problem, so no code to provide. My question is clear right? Can u show me your way?

Comment: Your question is not clear, no. Why are a3, d3, c1 and b0 special? You haven't given us the rule for producing the output.

Comment: Sorry about my mistake,["a3","d3","c1","b0"]

Comment: what do those 4 have in common exactly

Comment: oh ok, now I get it. Yes it is pretty easy to do

Comment: It base on suffix of them. Example: "a1","a2","a3". I want to get "a3"

Comment: @AlexW Iknow it is easy. Can u show me your answer.

Comment: Don't phrase your question like a riddle. Describe clearly what you want to achieve inside your question, not in the comments (you can do this by editing your question). I suppose you want to go through your array in reverse order and get only that element which first letter occurs the first time? If this is the case, please add this to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `Linq` statement does what you need.

```
var result= input.Select(x=> new {letter = x[0], number = x[1], item=x}) // Separate letter & number.
         .GroupBy(x=>x.letter)                                           // Group on letter and take first element (of max number)
         .Select(x=> x.OrderByDescending(o=>o.number).First())           
         .OrderByDescending(x=>x.number)                                 // Order on number.
         .Select(x=>x.item)                                              // get the item.
         .ToArray();
```

**Output**

```
[
   a3
   ,
   d3
   ,
   c1
   ,
   b0
]
```

Check this [`Example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9wqfXa)

Comment: Its allot shorter solution then the one i was going to post. Given the simplicity of the question, I was just going to use nested for loops  because I doubt he/she could understand LINQ

Comment: That's a great idea, it would helpful for beginners.

Comment: also @binh you should know when you have more than one digit, the code will only identify the first number

Comment: If he ask I will post my answer

Comment: That should be simple, one could easily separate string and the number based on the requirement. I let OP handle this case

Comment: @AlexW post it, nothing wrong in providing alternate solutions.

Comment: Thanks @HariPrasad. Your answer is very short and accurate. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AlexW Can you show me your answer. any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an alternative, its quite long mainly because I try to explain every line

```
// create list based on your original text
var list = new List<string> { "a1", "b0", "c0", "a2", "c1", "d3", "a3" };

// use a dictionary to hold the prefix and max suffixes
var suffixMaxDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

// loop through the list
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    // get the prefix using Substring()
    var prefix = list[i].Substring(0, 1);

    // if the prefix already exist in the dictionary then skip it, it's already been processed
    if (suffixMaxDictionary.ContainsKey(prefix))
        continue; // continue to the next item

    // set the max suffix to 0, so it can be checked against
    var suffixMax = 0;

    // loop through the whole list again to get the suffixes
    for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
    {
        // get the current prefix in the second loop of the list
        var thisprefix = list[j].Substring(0, 1);

        // if the prefixes don't match, then skip it
        // e.g. prefix = "a" and thisprefix = "b", then skip it
        if (prefix != thisprefix)
            continue;

        // get the suffix
        // warning though, it assumes 2 things:
        // 1. that the second character is a number
        // 2. there will only ever be numbers 0-9 as the second character
        var thisSuffix = Convert.ToInt32(list[j].Substring(1, 1));

        // check the current suffix number (thisSuffix) compared the suffixMax value
        if (thisSuffix > suffixMax)
        {
            // if thisSuffix > suffixMax, set suffixMax to thisSuffix 
            // and it will now become the new max value
            suffixMax = thisSuffix;
        }
    }
    // add the prefix and the max suffix to the dictionary
    suffixMaxDictionary.Add(prefix, suffixMax);
}
// print the values to the console
Console.WriteLine("original: \t" + string.Join(",", list));
Console.WriteLine("result: \t" + string.Join(",", suffixMaxDictionary));
Console.ReadLine();
```

See also https://dotnetfiddle.net/BmvFEp, thanks @Hari Prasad, I didn't know there was a fiddle for .net

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. 
I learned many things through your example.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the first instance of the largest "suffix" as described in the question:

```
string[] test = { "a3", "d3", "c1", "b0" };
string testResult = test.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Last<char>() == s.Max(t => s.Last<char>()));
```

In this case the result is "a3"